# Most efficient solution for USACO: Cow Gymnastics - Python

Tags: python, complexity

I was trying to figure out [this](http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=963) problem, and I did. However, my code is so abhorrently ugly that I want to tear out my eyeballs when I look at it:

```
with open("gymnastics.in", "r") as fin:
  rounds, cows = [int(i) for i in fin.readline().split()]
  nums = [tuple(map(int, line.split())) for line in fin]

def populatePairs(cows):
  pairs = []
  for i in range(cows):
      for j in range(cows):
          if i != j:
              pairs.append((i+1,j+1))
  return pairs

def consistentPairs(pairs, nums):
  results = []

  for i in pairs:
      asdf = True
      for num in nums:
          for j in num:
              if j == i[1]:
                  asdf = False
                  break
              if j == i[0]:
                  break
          if not asdf:
              break
      if asdf:
          results.append(i)

  return results

pairs = populatePairs(cows)

with open("gymnastics.out", "w+") as fout:
  print(len(consistentPairs(pairs, nums)), file=fout)
```

I feel like that there should definitely be a better solution that is faster than \$O(n^3)\$, and without the triple nested for-loop with the if-statements trailing behind them, but I cannot, for the love of god, think of a better solution.

**Problem synopsis:**

Given an \$n\$ by \$m\$ grid of points, find the number of pairs in which number is consistently placed before the other.

**Example:**

Input:

```
3 4
4 1 2 3
4 1 3 2
4 2 1 3
```

Output:
4

Explanation:
The consistent pairs of cows are (1,4), (2,4), (3,4), and (3,1), in which case 4 is consistently greater than all of them, and 1 is always greater than 3.

Comment: Do you have test cases with this?

Comment: @Mast yes. i'm going to edit the question with the test case included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Use the variable names from the problem specification instead of inventing your own (just make them lower-case since that's preferred in Python code). Makes it easier to see the connections. Unless yours are much better.
- I guess `nums` is plural so `num` is a single number, but you can iterate it? Bad name. And wth does `asdf` mean?
- Python prefers `snake_case` for function names.
- To be honest, the lack of any explanation of your method, the name `asdf` and the highly convoluted code made me give up reading it. But here's my solution, simply counting occurring pairs and then the result is the number of pairs that appeared K times:

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

ctr = Counter()
with open('gymnastics.in') as f:
    k, _ = map(int, next(f).split())
    for session in f:
        cows = session.split()
        ctr.update(combinations(cows, 2))

with open('gymnastics.out', 'w') as f:
    print(list(ctr.values()).count(k), file=f)
```

Comment: respect for the brutal honesty; i was incredibly tired when i was writing the code so i didnt put even an iota of thought into writing the variable/function names.

Comment: WAIT UR SOLUTION IS SO SMART WTF. jesus christ, mr. superb rain, you are incredibly cool